# keep iterating over a paginated dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a requirement where i am fetching response from a website and i am storing it as an json.But the problem is the response is limited(paginated) and it has a key "__next" where i can go to the next page and fetch the data .
My logic is iterate the response and find if "__next" is available or not ,if it is available the take the value(url) and fetch the next page data and iterate it until you find no "__next" key.

this the reponse

```
{
"results":[], 
"__next": "next page url"
}
```

i have written a function where i can fetch the result using url.
get_response("next page url")

this is my response function

```
def response_function(url_in):
    headers = {'Authorization':access_token ,'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept':'application/json'}
    r = requests.get(url_in, headers=headers)
    response = json.loads(r.content)
    print("inside for response function")
    return response.values()
response1 = response_function('first url')
skip_tokens = []
for i in response1:
    if  "__next" in i:
        # print(i["__next"])
        skip_tokens.append(i["__next"])
```

Answer (score 0):

considering that your `get_response` function returns a dictionary:

```
next_page_key = "__next"
partial_response = get_response("first_page_url")
while partial_response.get(next_page_key):
    next_url = partial_response.pop(next_page_key, None)
    partial_response.update(get_response(next_url))
```

Comment: I tried using your method 
while partial_response.get(next_page_key):
    partial_response.update(response_function(partial_response[next_page_key])
But it is throwing error.please see my edit code .

Comment: Also, your `get_response` function must return a dictionary for the code above to work. instead of `return response.values()` try `return response`

Comment: yes i was working on it ,seems like i might be able to get my desired output,just need to format my response

Comment: I modified my function 
`partial_response = response_function('url')
while partial_response["__next"]:
    partial_response.update(response_function(partial_response["__next"]))
    print(partial_response)`
But it's an never ending loop 
It should iterate 4 times because

Comment: 2 questions: is "__next" key always in response? What is the value of "__next" key in the response dictionary when it reaches the last page

Comment: that  "__next" key contains url for the next page and i put that in my function response_function( "__next") and it shall continue until it can't find the  "__next" anymore in the response

Comment: It might be because "_next" is still in the partial_response dict. Edited the answer with a pop to to make sure that the loop will only continue if the key is returned in response

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, you'd like help writing some algorithm to iterate over this segmented data you get. It's easy to achieve this by using a generator, like this:

```py
def get_data(url):
  res, next_url = fetch_data_from_website(url)

  while res:
    for item in res:
      yield item # NOTE: Error before fixing the answer was here

    if next_url:
      res, next_url = fetch_data_from_website(next_url)
```

Where `fetch_data_from_website()` is a function that gets as input a url and returns the results and next URL (or `None`) as a tuple. This will allow to transparently iterate over the chunks.

You will now be able to iterate through the whole split collection as follows:

```py
for x in get_data(url):
  do_something_with_element(x)
```

Comment: it takes me into an infinite loop :(

Comment: @GeraldSchwarz It's my fault, sorry. I am yielding `res` while I should be yielding `item`. Will fix it and add a comment to show the error

Comment: NameError: name 'item' is not defined
because my res is a list .

Comment: @GeraldSchwarz `res` is supposed to be a list but you spotted another mistake of mine. Sorry, I'm working and didn't run the code first. I should not be using a `while` loop in the second iteration but a `for` loop! Fixed.

Comment: what's the item in the while loop ? where have you defined it ?

Comment: @GeraldSchwarz as you can see in the corrected answer, it's not a `while` loop anymore, it's now a `for` loop. `item` is an item from the list returned in the JSON object coming from the website you're querying. It's automatically defined by the `for` loop.

Comment: I did some changes ,but now i need to append the result 
`def get_data(url):
    try :
        data = response_function(url)
        res, next_url = data["results"],data["__next"]
        while next_url:
            finalResponse = {}
            for item in res:
                finalResponse.update(item)
                yield finalResponse 
            if next_url:
                data = response_function(next_url)
                res, next_url = data["results"],data["__next"]
            break
    except:
        pass
for x in get_data('url'):
    print(x)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216276/discussion-between-alqafir-and-gerald-schwarz).